# Is this a Google Chrome extensions bug?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wanted to make a Google Chrome extension that needed to list the `<script>` tags on a web page. So I made a `manifest.json` with a script that would `"run_at": "document_start"` only on that particular web page. When I loaded the page, I noticed that the value of `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` was that of an array with the proper `<script>` element in it, but its length was 0 and I couldn't access the elements.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
console.log(scripts.length); // 0
console.log(scripts); // [<script type=​"text/​javascript">​...</script>​] with expected JavaScript in it
```

Something somewhere is definitely wrong. The `scripts` variable has length 0 but the console shows it contains an element which cannot be accessed.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html):

> In the case of "document_start", the files are injected after any files from css, but **before any other DOM is constructed** or any other script is run.

If you need access to the DOM, change `run_at` to `document_end` or leave it as the default `document_idle`.